# Python - variable is getting set to 0 and can't figure out why

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame

Okay, so I'm making a little game with pygame and building the map by generating tiles to a multidimensional array. In order to do that I'm using two for loops.

```
def create(this, t):

    if t == "grasslands":
        for j in range(0, this.numRows):
            for i in range(0, this.numColumns):
                this.column.append(this.Tile("grass", j * this.tileWidth, i * this.tileHeight))
            this.row.append(this.column)
```

The value for **j * this.tileWidth** is getting passed into the Tile initialization correctly. After though the **column[whatever].x** value is still 0. The **y** value gets set just fine, and if I use **i** or any other value instead of **j** things work just fine. Is this something I'm doing wrong or something wonky with Python?

***mapgen.py***

```
import pygame
from sprite import *
from assets import *

class mapG:

def __init__(this, resw, resh):
    this.numRows = 3
    this.numcolumns = 3
    this.tileWidth = 128
    this.tileHeight = 128

    this.row = []
    this.column = []
    this.width = this.numRows * this.tileWidth
    this.height = this.numcolumns * this.tileHeight


def create(this, t):

    if t == "grasslands":
        for j in range(0, this.numRows):
            for i in range(0, this.numcolumns):
                this.column.append(this.Tile("grass", j * this.tileWidth, i * this.tileHeight))
            this.row.append(this.column)


def tileAt(this, x, y):
    pass

def moveRight(this):
    for j in range(0,this.numRows):
        for i in range(0, this.numcolumns):
            this.row[j][i].incX(1)

def Update(this, src):
    for j in range(0,this.numRows):
        for i in range(0, this.numcolumns):
            this.row[j][i].Update(src)
            print(this.row[j][i].y, this.row[j][i].x)

class Tile:

    def __init__(this, name, xpos, ypos):
        this.y = ypos
        this.x = xpos
        this.image = assets.tile[name + ".png"]
        this.sprite = sprite(this.image, this.x, this.y, 100, 100)

    def incX(this, amount):
        this.sprite.IncX(amount)

    def decX(this, amount):
        this.sprite.DecX(amount)

    def incY(this, amount):
        this.sprite.IncY(amount)

    def decY(this, amount):
        this.sprite.DecY(amount)

    def Update(this, src = None):
        if src != None:
            this.sprite.Update(src)
```

***sprite.py***

```
import pygame
import assets

class sprite:

def __init__(this, image, xpos, ypos, width = None, height = None):

    this.image = image
    this.x = xpos
    this.y = ypos
    this.width = width
    this.height = height

    if this.width != None and this.height != None:
        this.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (this.width,this.height))

def GetPos(this):
    return (this.x, this.y)

def IncX(this, amount):
    this.x += amount

def IncY(this, amount):
    this.y += amount

def DecX(this, amount):
    this.x -= amount

def DecY(this, amount):
    this.y -= amount

def Update(this, src = None):
    if src != None:
        src.blit(this.image, this.GetPos())
```

Comment: Please get out of the habit of using `this`, in Python the convention is `self`

Comment: try float(j) and see what happens

Comment: @Wallace Just tried that, didn't fix it.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger or debugging print statements?

Comment: @Patashu Yes, I've tired several debugging print statements. The value for j goes into the initialization of Tile() correctly and sets the Tile().x value correctly but immediately after it's x value is still 0. The strange part is if I pass a set value into there, or i, it works fine.

Comment: print type(j) and see what you get

Comment: What is `this.tileWidth`?

Comment: @Wallace <class 'int'>

Comment: @Patashu The width of the tiles, I'm using the tile width times the row it is in to figure out it's x position. The y position is working fine, just not the x position.

Comment: @jamylak I know I need too. I'm still new to Python and old habits and all that.

Comment: @Zexanima What I mean is, is it 0? if so then you will pass in j*0 e.g. 0

Comment: @Patashu It is set to 128. I've also tired passing in 128 directly and it didn't fix it.

Comment: when you print row are all the x's 0?

Comment: @Wallace Yes. Unless I change j to something else.

Comment: lol just making sure.  I'm getting the correct data when i run it so I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I think the most important thing I can say is - it's almost guaranteed it's not some kind of compiler or interpreter bug. Question assumptions you've made about everything that you don't know for a 100% fact works as written.

Comment: @Wallace Thanks for the help! Guess I'll have to figure it out on my own.

Comment: @Patashu That's what I was doing, and when I ran out of ideas I came here. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the issue you have comes from your use of the `this.column` variable in the `create` method.

You're only creating one column list (in `__init__`) and then reusing it for all the columns of your map. This won't work.

Your `this.row` list ends up having multiple references to the same column list, which ends up containing all of the `Tile` objects you create. You only see some of them later, since your iteration code uses predefined dimensions, rather than actually iterating over the whole of the lists.

To understand this, try to imagine how the iteration progresses for a 2x2 grid (ignoring the tile dimensions). I'm putting each `i` and `j` value on it's own line to show how it progresses, and giving the values of `row` and `columns` after each step side:

```
j=0:
   i=0:
      column.append(Tile(i, j))
      # column is [Tile(0, 0)]
      # row is []

   i=1:
      column.append(Tile(i, j))
      # column is [Tile(0, 0), Tile(0, 1)]
      # row is []

   row.append(column)
   # column is [Tile(0, 0), Tile(0, 1)]
   # row is [[Tile(0, 0), Tile(0, 1)]]

j=1: # column is not reset!
   i=0:
      column.append(Tile(i, j))
      # column is [Tile(0, 0), Tile(0, 1), Tile(1, 0)]
      # row is [[Tile(0, 0), Tile(0, 1), Tile(1, 0)]]

   i=1:
      column.append(Tile(i, j))
      # column is [Tile(0, 0), Tile(0, 1), Tile(1, 0), Tile(1, 1)]
      # row is [[Tile(0, 0), Tile(0, 1), Tile(1, 0), Tile(1, 1)]]

   row.append(column)
   # column is [Tile(0, 0), Tile(0, 1), Tile(1, 0), Tile(1, 1)]
   # row is [[Tile(0, 0), Tile(0, 1), Tile(1, 0), Tile(1, 1)],
   #          [Tile(0, 0), Tile(0, 1), Tile(1, 0), Tile(1, 1)]]
```

The `row` list contains two references to the same `column` list of four tiles. Your code had intended to add the first two `Tile(0, 0)` and `Tile(0,1)` to the first column, then the last two tiles `Tile(1, 0)` and `Tile(1, 1)` to the second column. But because the same list was used both times, you end up with all the values together, and then the whole bunch repeated. When you iterate, you're only seeing the repeated values on the left part of the diagram above.

Here's how to fix it:

```
def create(this, t):
    if t == "grasslands":
        for j in range(0, this.numRows):

            column = [] # Create a new list! This is the key!

            for i in range(0, this.numColumns):
                column.append(this.Tile("grass",
                              j * this.tileWidth,
                              i * this.tileHeight))
            this.row.append(column)
```

You can get rid of the line in the constructor that initializes `self.column` too. It's only needed temporarily, so there's no need to use an instance variable.

Comment: Wow, I feel a bit dim witted now. Thanks a ton for the help Blckknght!

Answer (score 0):

You don't end up creating rows of width 3 (`numColumns`). You end up with rows of width 9 (rows*cols) since you don't create a new row each time through the loop.

Your loop should look like this:

```
for j in range(0, this.numRows):
    row=[]
    for i in range(0, this.numColumns):
        row.append(this.Tile("grass", j * this.tileWidth, i * this.tileHeight))
    this.rows.append(row)
```

And then you probably ended up looking at the wrong data when you were debugging it, not realizing the row was longer than you expected. (Also the names are a bit confusing, so I changed them a bit.)